# Why does $\int_0^ae^\frac1x x^pdx$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Let $a$ be positive and $p$ be real.

Why does the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{a}{\rm e}^{1/x} x^{p}\,{\rm d}x$$ diverge ?

Direct integration over $\left[b,a\right]$ for positive $b$ is hard. On the other hand, although I know that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}{{\rm d}x \over x^{k}}$ diverges for all positive-integral $k$, I can't find a good comparison (i.e. $\frac 1{x^k}<e^\frac1x x^p$, i.e. $e^\frac1x x^{p+k}>1$) to prove what I want.

Comment: I do not know how much this would help you but the antiderivative is x^(1 + p) ExpIntegralE[2 + p, -(1/x)] and I guess that the problem is with the (1/x) term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{a}\expo{1/x}x^{p}\,\dd x &= \int_{\infty}^{1/a}\expo{x}x^{-p}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
=
\int^{\infty}_{1/a}\expo{x}x^{-p - 2}\,\dd x\quad\mbox{diverges !!!}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I did this substition too (following your previous example), but I couldn't see that the final expression diverges. But now on thinking harder, I see that L'Hopital's rule can be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if we apply [Quotient Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx) as follows then it diverges:

$$p\ge0\to k=-p\le0<1 \to \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^kf(x)=\infty$$ And $$p<0\to\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\color{red}{1}}f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: @amWhy: Dear Amy, I have got catch cold badly and I am on way to visit a doctor. :-(

Comment: @amWhy: Nice to see you :-) Thanks I am feeling better. Taking pills makes every one goods. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Oh dear. I inly hope you are getting well so soon. We have just a unique Amy at this site. A shinning one! :-)